# Why React-Tooltip is generated several times in array.map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

lately I've started to work with ReactJS and I'm a super beginner. It might be a really easy question, but I don't know how to fix this error.

I had 3 images in this.state , and spread them out to the screen by using .map(). And there's ReactTooltip which I downloaded from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

But there's some error that I can't fix, it isn't even shown to console screen. The problem is whenever you put your mouse point on an image, ReactTooltip has been generated multiple times. Can anyone please help me out to fix this?

Here's my code and example demo.
Demo:http://tooltip-test-moonformeli.c9users.io/ 
Code:[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are using ReactTooltip component incorrectly. You only have to include ReactTooltip component once and you should specify your tooltip text to each element with `data-tip` attribute. So you can change your render function to something like follows.

```
render(){
    const mapToState = this.state.data.map(planet, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <img data-tip={planet} src={planet}/>
        </div>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {mapToState}
        <ReactTooltip/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Oh god, you're my hero. It works!! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as the correct answer. :)